# NppExec Command and Output History

Tags: python-3.x

Hi when I run the program in the NotePad++.  Every time, the console refresh and the previous output is gone. How can I execute the code without replacing previous command history? [For example, if I execute the command print "Hello the World" several times, the previous one is gone and only the newest execution remains on the console.  Can I kept the previous history?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsz8S.png)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: read what NppExec prints in its Console as a result of typing

```
help npe_console
```

Longer answer:

```
npe_console a+/a-  append mode (don't clear Console) on/off
a+/a-  Console append mode on/off.
     There is no corresponding menu item.
     This option is not saved when you close Notepad++.
     Default value: off
     (Console is automatically cleared when new script starts).
```